# Why is Rsync failing to sync a specific folder?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, rsync

We are using rsync when syncing to our dev server on GCP. Recently ive noticed that it does not sync some of our files in a specific folder. The others work well like before.

This is how our trigger looks like:
First one is working

```
rsync -aqe ssh \
    --no-g \
    --no-p \
    --delete \
    --force \
    --dirs \
    --perms \
    --no-owner \
    --no-group \
    --exclude-from="/opt/projects/puppet/devtools/sync_script/support_files/sync_web.exclude" \
    --log-file="/tmp/rsync.log" \
    /opt/projects/web/src/ \
    "${DEV_IP}":/var/www/src/
```

Not working example:

```
rsync -aqe ssh \
    --no-g \
    --no-p \
    --delete \
    --force \
    --dirs \
    --perms \
    --no-owner \
    --no-group \
    --exclude-from="/opt/projects/puppet/devtools/sync_script/support_files/sync_web.exclude" \
    --log-file="/tmp/rsync.log" \
    /opt/projects/web/ \
    "${DEV_IP}":/var/www/
```

So when we specifinc that folder it works. But if use one level up from it thoose files will not be synced.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, it is best to turn off the -q option, which would indicate if there is an error. In case there is no error you can always try to debug with

```
-v, --verbose               increase verbosity
    --info=FLAGS            fine-grained informational verbosity
    --debug=FLAGS           fine-grained debug verbosity
```

you can also check the rsync.log log file.

Comment: The only thing i see in the log files is that our files in src, is building when i specify that in the path as seen in my post.

Comment: This answer does not address the actual issue in the question, but offers advice on usage and how to get more detailed information about the problem. Consider adding this as a comment, instead of an answer.